# Is it possible to control the system only from remote connection using VNC Server?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, rhel7, vnc

I have a Linux computer with VNC server running in it. When I connect to that computer remotely from another computer using a Remote Desktop Viewing application, the main computer display is still visible and any person can control it.

**How can I lock the screen or remove access to control(keyboard, mouse) the main computer when connected to it remotely.**

Can I have the same behaviour how RDP works on a windows system? Lock the screen when someone is logged in remotely?

By the way I am using x0vncserver for sharing the existing display.

Comment: Don’t run VNC from the local session in desktop sharing mode but configure it to run independently as a separate session https://docs.01.org/clearlinux/latest/guides/network/vnc.html

Comment: Thanks @HermanB I think you are asking me to create a new virtual display and use it. But the problem is that during any network link failure, the person at the main computer should take over and continue operating from the state at which it is left.

Answer (score 0):

Use Remotely from https://remotely.one/
this can do what you wont and more. free to use in commercial environments too.
if this help for anyone, give a donation to the developer in remotely.one to make the software keep on developing.